# Why does "font-weight: bolder" skip boldness steps?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

According to the [MDN page on font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) and other sources, `font-weight: bolder` makes text content *"one font weight darker than the parent element (among the available weights of the font)."*

I have a test page with the "Open Sans" font included from Google Fonts, with the weights 300, 400 (aka "normal"), 600, 700 (aka "bold"), and 800. Setting the numeric font weights manually works as expected, but using `bolder` seems to skip the font weight 600.

Firefox and Chrome agree on this, so I'm probably misunderstanding what "one step" means in this context.

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D3vKQ/) for testing, and a screenshot of the results I'm getting.

[image]

The first section has manual numeric `font-weight` settings. The second has nested `div` blocks styled with `font-weight: lighter` (works as expected), the third has nested `div` blocks with `font-weight: bolder`; this one shows the effect I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`font-weight` section of the CSS2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-boldness):

> Values of 'bolder' and 'lighter' indicate values relative to the weight of the parent element. Based on the inherited weight value, the weight used is calculated using the chart below. Child elements inherit the calculated weight, not a value of 'bolder' or 'lighter'.

```
Inherited val   bolder  lighter
100             400     100
200             400     100
300             400     100
400             700     100
500             700     100
600             900     400
700             900     400
800             900     700
900             900     700
```

This means that anything `bolder` than a `font-weight` of 400 is given a weight of 700, and anything bolder than a font-weight of 700 is given a weight of 900.

This is exactly what is happening in your JSFiddle demo.

#### Bolder

```html
This is some text with weight 400.        <!-- 400 -->
This text is one step bolder than above.  <!-- bolder than 400 = 700 -->
This text is one step bolder than above.  <!-- bolder than 700 = 900 -->
This text is one step bolder than above.  <!-- bolder than 900 = 900 -->
This text is one step bolder than above.  <!-- ... -->
```

#### Lighter

```html
This is some text with weight 400.        <!-- 400 -->
This text is one step lighter than above. <!-- lighter than 400 = 100 -->
This text is one step lighter than above. <!-- lighter than 100 = 100 -->
This text is one step lighter than above. <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Your Google-fu is faster than mine. */bows*

Comment: @OnoSendai it helps to have the various specifications bookmarked. :)

Comment: Touché! I remember running into that issue previously, but I must confess I had to look it up.

Comment: Of course, that explains everything. What was I thinking, looking at other sources instead of going directly to the specs...

Comment: Because you used logic, @Zilk, and that's the best approach on most cases. But sometimes specs defies logic - or maybe there's a reason, convoluted as it may be.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking from pure logic, you're correct. But according to the [W3C recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-boldness), that is not so. Quoting the document:

> Values of 'bolder' and 'lighter' indicate values relative to the
>   weight of the parent element. Based on the inherited weight value, the
>   weight used is calculated using the chart below. Child elements
>   inherit the calculated weight, not a value of 'bolder' or 'lighter'.

```
[Inherited value]   [bolder]    [lighter]
100                 400         100
200                 400         100
300                 400         100
400                 700         100
500                 700         100
600                 900         400
700                 900         400
800                 900         700
900                 900         700
```